# Security Chipsec

Tags: physical, antimalware

Is it right to believe that if the Chipsec scan, Malwarebytes Anti Rootkit scan and Tdsskiller all come clean, your computer OS and hardware are all clean with no malware, rootkit, Rat or anything else and there is no chance of your information being misused?

Please elaborate if it's wrong to believe that as I want to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

> there is no chance of your information being misused.

This line is what is going to get you in trouble.  I know what you are asking, but this phrase will raise the hairs on the back of any security expert worth their salt.  You are *never* certain that there's no chance that something will be misused.  Never ever ever ever ever ever ever ever ever.  Period.  Full stop.

There's a famous quote along these lines:

> The only truly secure computer is one which is disconnected from the internet, powered down, unplugged, stored in a concrete bunker several floors below the surface with armed guards patrolling above.  Even then, I'd check on it every now and then.

Now, talking practically, you can be *confident* that your computer is clean after that many steps.  To gauge how confident you are, we'd have to talk about threat models.  Who are you trying to protect your information from?  Is it some script kiddie down the street?  The mob?  Other countries or three letter agencies?  Each has progressively more subtle ways of exploiting your data.  The local script kiddie is going to be completely stymmed by all the steps you took.  The mafia?  They're probably stopped.  I don't know if they have the tools or not, but they've got less paranoid fish to catch.  For them, it's all about the money and the ROI.

Three letter agencies?  Well, let's just say that Stuxnet famously jumped an airgap in a highly classified Iranian nuclear enrichment facility and did serious damage.  If they can do that, I'm *certain* they can infect your computer without you knowing if they really wanted to.

Never seek perfect security.  It doesn't exist, and it's a waste because you can always get hit by a car tomorrow, rendering all that security moot.  Seek a balance of security, accessibility, and usability based on the threats you are concerned with.